# Why doesn't BigQuery optimize a LEFT JOIN and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have the following query:

```
#standardSQL

WITH users AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'pieter' name UNION ALL
  SELECT 2   , 'george'      UNION ALL
  SELECT 3   , 'maggie'
),
invoices AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 1 userId, 25.0 amount, 'taxi fee' description UNION ALL
  SELECT 2   , 1       , 300.0      , 'conference ticket'    UNION ALL
  SELECT 3   , 1       , 300.0      , 'hotel room'           UNION ALL
  SELECT 5   , 3       , 70         , 'airbnb'               UNION ALL
  SELECT 6   , 3       , 22         , 'concert ticket'
)
SELECT
  users.id userId,
  users.name userName
FROM 
  users
LEFT JOIN 
  invoices ON invoices.userId = users.id
GROUP BY
  users.id,
  users.name
ORDER BY
  users.id
```

In this case the combination of a LEFT JOIN and GROUP BY can easily be optimized (omitted) by the query processor. However when I look in the query plan the join is still executed by BigQuery. Why? And how can I avoid this behaviour?

My use case: I have **a view** containing a few fields requiring such joins. I don't want the joins to be executed when the fields aren't queried.

I'm using the `standardSQL` dialect.

Comment: Query optimizers are usually designed to figure out hard algorithmic problems, not to rewrite poorly written queries.  And, what difference does the join actually make?  Obviously, your real problem involves tables with more than 5 rows, so your real question is quite different from what is being asked here.

Comment: Why are you using a group by at all without any aggregates?  Do you mean distinct?   For that matter since you have no data form invoices being used; why even join to invoices?  too little info.

Comment: Of course It's just a reduced example. In my real world problem I'm querying a few fields from a view containing joins which aren't required for the query.

Comment: @wardva . . . Your question regarding view optimization is a very good point and worth bringing up with BQ developers.  It would not generate quite the same reaction as the question you actually asked.

Comment: To bring on BQ engineers please post a job id of your query.

Comment: I think Gordon nailed it.  optimizers are not built to fix bad code.  they assume coders would only join to a table when data is needed from it.  Part of it may have to do with order of operation.  the optimizer doesn't know the table and join isn't needed until all aspects of the query have been finalized by that point the join is already done...  it's an interesting question really meant for those that code database engine;  which I'm not.  Target audience for this question appears to be BQ engineers; not the general SO user base.

Comment: JobId of the actual query: `spry-framework-483:US.bquijob_77ec7ccb_161b5092194`

Comment: "How can I avoid this behavior?" Don't write a query that joins a table where you don't need any fields from the joined table. :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff while this may be true, it's certainly not true of code compilers generally, which arguably a query optimizer is. The compilers for .NET, for example, often do a lot of optimizing away of poorly-written code.

Comment: @theMayer For the 867th time: I have a view with a few columns containing values generated by aggregating on joined values. I don't want the joins to be executed when I don't select any of these columns.

Comment: @wardva - then create another view with fewer columns. It seems that having more columns than you want kind of defeats the purpose of using a view. I'm not saying you haven't found a bug, but much time has been spent looking at this with not a whole lot of usefulness.

Answer (score 3):

Let me elaborate on my comment.

You probably do not appreciate all the different ways that a query could be executed.  Let me step outside BQ (which I know a bit about but definitely am lacking in in-depth knowledge) and point out some algorithms used for joining and aggregating:

- join:  nested loop
- join:  nested loop using an index on one table
- join:  index merge
- join:  sort and merge
- join:  hash and match, with in-memory and out-of-memory variants
- aggregation:  hash-based
- aggregation:  sort-based
- aggregation:  index-based
- parallel versions of all the above

I realize the index-based approaches are not applicable to BQ.  But these are to give you a flavor.  Then, after choosing a particular algorithm, there may still be parameters and submethods -- what sort algorithm to use?  How big a hash table?  How to handle collisions?  BQ has its own parameters that need to be set, with regards to parallelism and skew.

These are hard problems solved by an optimizer.  The folks who write them come to work (perhaps remotely) each day.  They have a choice:

- Do I want to work on fixing poorly written queries where the writer should know how to write it better?
- Do I want to figure out the best algorithms and implementations for general classes of queries that might affect all users?

EDIT:

In the comments, the OP points out that s/he is actually referring to a *view*.  That is an entirely different animal, and join elimination is a very reasonable optimization strategy in that case.